# ImportError: No module named durationfield.db.models.fields.duration (Python, Django 1.9)

Tags: python, django, import, models, duration

I'm trying to put a duration field in my models and I'm following the instructions [here](https://django-durationfield.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  First problems I run into is that I can't seem to import the module.  Doesn't this come standard with Django?

```
    from durationfield.db.models.fields.duration import DurationField
ImportError: No module named durationfield.db.models.fields.duration
```

Following Daniel Roseman's suggestion, I changed this to:

```
from django.db.models.field.duration
```

Now I'm getting:

```
ImportError: No module named duration
```

Answer (score 2):

It's here:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField
```

And yes, it comes with Django 1.8+ so you don't need to install it.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything that needs to go in the forms?  I'm still getting this error message: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (duration) specified for Offer

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing from django.db.models....

Comment: You **specifically** linked to a third-party project which said it was a temporary fix until it was included in Django. Why don't you read the actual [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) instead?